# How to delete an item inside an XML with a certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML variable value like this in SQL. (SQL SERVER 18)

```
   DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(55) = '123'
   DECLARE @XML XML = '<NewData>
      <XML>
        <PONo>123</SAPPONo>
        <Brand>Goldilucks</Brand>
        <Color>Amber Brown</Color>
        <Size>L</Size>
        <OrderQty>21</OrderQty>
        <FinalOrderQty>21</FinalOrderQty>
        <Unit>KG</Unit>
        <DeliveryDate>2021-07-09T00:00:00+08:00</DeliveryDate>
        <BatchNo>GC-L1</BatchNo>
        <ExpiryDate>2021-08-23T00:00:00+08:00</ExpiryDate>
      </XML>
    </NewData>'
```

I want to remove the
`<BatchNo>GC-L1</BatchNo>` and `<ExpiryDate>2021-08-23T00:00:00+08:00</ExpiryDate>`
if the `<PONo> = '123'`.

How can I achieve that in SQL?

I am trying this solution

```
SET @XML.modify('delete /NewDataSet/XML/BatchNo'[PONo = sql:variable(@result)])
SET @XML.modify('delete /NewDataSet/XML/ExpiryDate'[PONo = sql:variable(@result)])
```

But the said items still exist in my XML.

Thank you

Comment: @TT. I indicated the database I am using Sir. thank you!

Comment: @DaleK , I have attached my sample solution.

Comment: Your code contains all sorts of syntax errors and name mismatches. `PONo` doesn't match `SAPPONo`, there is no `NewDataSet`, your `SET` will not run, etc. Assuming the obvious errors are fixed in the obvious way, a statement like `SET @XML.modify('delete /NewData/XML[SAPPONo = sql:variable("@result")]/BatchNo')` would do it. Both nodes can be removed in one step with `SET @XML.modify('delete /NewData/XML[SAPPONo = sql:variable("@result")]/*[self::BatchNo or self::ExpiryDate]')`.